# PHP - get proper value type and encode the right JSON string

Tags: php, json

I have a php code as a test like this:

```
$myObj->string = "myString";
$myObj->number = 111;
$objects = json_encode($myObj);
echo $objects;
```

the echo i get shows **111** as a number, not a string, which is what i need:

```
{“string”:”myString”,”number”:111}
```

But, if i send a form like the one one below to my `save.php` file, the **111** value gets wrapped into “”, so it becomes a string.

My form:

```
<form action="save.php">
  <input type="text" name="string">
  <input type="number" name="number">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

the values i type in the input areas are:
**myString

111**

My `save.php` file:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $objects->$key = $value;
}// ./ foreach
$objs = json_encode($objects);
echo $objs;
```

the echo i get is:

```
{“string”:”myString”,”number”:”111”}
```

which is not right since i need to get a number, so it should be like: “number”:**111**

What am i missing, or doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Everything that comes from an HTML form is a string. You will need to parse it after you obtain the value to make it a number again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if the string is numeric, and then force it to be handled accordingly:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) 
{
    if( is_numeric($value) )
    {
        $objects->$key = (float) $value;
    }
    else
    {
        $objects->$key = $value;
    }
}

$objs = json_encode($objects);

echo $objs;
```

Assuming your PHP version is `> 5.3.2`, you can also use the [`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) constant on `json_encode()`:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) 
{
    $objects->$key = $value;
}
$objs = json_encode($objects, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $objs;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$objs = json_encode($objects, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

> JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK
>       Encodes numeric strings as numbers. Available since PHP 5.3.3.  http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php